# How can I change my own library's index.js to import it as local object, not as global one?

Tags: javascript, npm, import, export

Currently I have index.js file in my library.

```
import method1 from './method1';
import method2 from './method2';

(function(window){
  window.myLib = {
    processArray,
    processString,
  }
})(window);
```

And if I wanna use this library, I should do like:

```
import 'my-lib';
myLib.method1();
```

How can I refactor my index.js to not use global object and use this library like:

```
import myLyb from 'my-lib';
myLib.method1();
```

Comment: add it into node_modules

Comment: Is defining the method on `window` necessary?

Comment: You will want to look into the [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I did this for a custom library of my own.

Using the modern Class syntax, assuming this file was called `MyLib.js`:

```
class MyLib {

   constructor() {
     // do stuff
   }

   // other functions that do stuff

   processArray() {

   }

   processString() {

   }

}

export default MyLib;
```

In your other code, such as `index.js`, you'd import and use your library like this:

```
import MyLib from './MyLib'

// later on

MyLib.processArray()
MyLib.processString()
```